# How to indicate to chrome the download priority (low, high or highest) of the feature modules in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I have programmed a customized preload strategy of modules in angular and loading delays to simulate order of priority ([Example](https://medium.com/@muthudevendra/angular-custom-preloading-strategy-32abe99944f8)). Although everything is loaded correctly in the pre-loaded one, in Chrome Devtool the modules are downloaded with low priority, how can I set the chrome download priority from angular 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking there isn't a specific Angular-way of assigning priorities to lazy-loaded/preloaded components. Anyway I'll try to give you some ideas because I'm also interesed in this issue.

I suppose you already read what Google says about the priorities of downloaded resources on a web page:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization
  (**TLDR** from highest to lowest: *CSS* -> *preload as=style* -> *head scripts* -> *async* -> *preload as=script* -> *defer*)
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/priority-hints
  (**TLDR** an additional ***importance*** attribute on resource tags, that takes *high*, *low* or *auto* as its' value)

The sad part is that even though these solutions/workarounds seem to work well in Chrome, they aren't part of any standard so there's no warranty other browsers will  consider them to adjust resource priorities.

As an Angular solution, what comes to my mind is using [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)s to load any required dependencies that need *"high"* priority, or at least be loaded when the application is initialized (just before the startup).

Another idea that could be helpful is using [Service Workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) where you can specify cache strategies, including a performance oriented one. As I could figure out inspecting a site I'm working on, resources handled by the service worker are downloaded with high priority, but I guess your mileage may vary.

Hope it helps, and best regards from Chile.
José Ignacio

Comment: Thank you very much, I liked the idea of ​​the service worker.